# get data from dynamic class="????" from bs4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Can I use dynamic class ie class="cfBD1" and class="cfJLC" or class="????" to get the  = "data" from  tag?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup=BeautifulSoup("""<div class="couponTable"><div id="tgCou1" class="tgCoupon couponRow"><span class="spBtnMinus"></span><!-- react-text: 67 -->Wednesday Matches<!-- /react-text --></div><div class="couponRow rAlt1 tgCou1" id="rmid20180905WED1"><img src="/ContentServer/jcbw/images/flag_JLC.gif?CV=L302R1g" alt="Japanese League Cup" title="Japanese League Cup" class="cfJLC"><img src="/ContentServer/jcbw/images/icon_tv-C661.gif?CV=L302R1g" alt="C661-i-CABLE 661 C601-i-CABLE 601" title="C661-i-CABLE 661 C601-i-CABLE 601"></span></span><img src="/football/info/images/btn_odds.gif?CV=L302R1g" alt="All Odds" title="All Odds"></a></div><div class="couponRow rAlt0 tgCou1" id="rmid20180905WED2"><img src="/ContentServer/jcbw/images/flag_JLC.gif?CV=L302R1g" alt="Japanese League Cup" title="Japanese League Cup" class="cfJLC"><img src="/ContentServer/jcbw/images/icon_tv-C662.gif?CV=L302R1g" alt="C662-i-CABLE 662 C602-i-CABLE 602" title="C662-i-CABLE 662 C602-i-CABLE 602"></span></span><img src="/football/info/images/btn_odds.gif?CV=L302R1g" alt="All Odds" title="All Odds"></a></div></div></div><div class="couponRow rAlt1 tgCou1" id="rmid20180905WED12"><img src="/ContentServer/jcbw/images/flag_BD1.gif?CV=L302R1g" alt="Brazilian Division 1" title="Brazilian Division 1" class="cfBD1"><img src="/football/info/images/btn_odds.gif?CV=L302R1g" alt="All Odds" title="All Odds"></a></div></div>""",'html.parser')

lines=soup.find_all('img')
for line in lines:
    print(line['alt'])
```

Output :

```
Japanese League Cup
C661-i-CABLE 661 C601-i-CABLE 601
All Odds
Japanese League Cup
C662-i-CABLE 662 C602-i-CABLE 602
All Odds
Brazilian Division 1
All Odds
```

Expected Output:

```
Japanese League Cup
Japanese League Cup
Brazilian Division 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you can just check if the `img` tag has the `class` attribute:

```
soup.find_all('img', attrs={'class': True})
```

**Example:**

```
In [1570]: [img['alt'] for img in soup.find_all('img', attrs={'class': True})]
Out[1570]: ['Japanese League Cup', 'Japanese League Cup', 'Brazilian Division 1']
```

---

For completeness, matching any dynamic attribute value, you need to find a common pattern in the naming e.g. in this case it seems all the class names start with character `c`; so, you can use the CSS selector:

```
img[class^="c"]
```

**Example:**

```
In [1571]: [img['alt'] for img in soup.select('img[class^="c"]')]
Out[1571]: ['Japanese League Cup', 'Japanese League Cup', 'Brazilian Division 1']
```